# DIY lie down computer workstation

Tags: furniture, self-assembly-furniture

I am suffering from lower back pain and looking to build a lie down workstation.

What I have came up is this:

1. Adjustable bed for a little recline to stay comfortable for long working hours. Bed will be placed besides wall in parallel.
2. Monitor pulldown and pull up arrangement right on top of bed at the eye level. With Horizontal and vertical tilt.
3. Slim keyboard and mouse tray fitted to the wall on one side, and totally adjustable on top of bed at tummy level.

I want something exactly like this but want to lower the anchoring costs:

[image]

I don't have much idea about what material and ready made items to use to accomplish this.

Looking forward for completing this project asap. Any tips greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Voting to close. This seems far more like a product recommendation question.

Comment: Not a ready product. I won't get this ready made anywhere. I am trying to build it with the help of a carpenter.

Comment: It's not necessarily a product question, but it is very broad. "Any tips" questions tend to be off-topic for that reason. You'll need to do some research and come back with more specific questions about your plan. [Take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about what makes a good question.

Comment: Thanks for guidelines. I just want the 3 mentioned points covered in my product.

Comment: @isherwood does that make a little bit more specific?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, project type questions like this are off-topic here.

Comment: @daniel Can you suggest another stackexchange site that would be suitable for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You might try one of the more discussion-oriented sites. (Hope your back gets better soon.)

Comment: Thank you @Daniel I'll keep this question open and once I'm done building my project I would come here and post the results. If the mods think its better to close, then so be it.

Comment: Well now it seems like you _are_ asking for product recommendations. We can't do that. It would make a mess of this network if we became a substitute for Google.

Comment: i have read you post several times and i do not see any questions being asked .... all i see is a description of a proposed project

Comment: @Zid Did you ever build something? I need something like this too and have made a crude version so far. I'm moving now and need to build another. I'd love to trade ideas and experience.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but you could just buy something like this [Computer Monitor Wall Mount](http://www.afcindustries.com/height-adjustable-wall-mounted-computer-station-p1227) and attach it to the wall:

[image: Computer monitor wall mount]

It's adjustable in a few different ways:

[image]

Or there are ones more like a table, for a laptop, like this [Track Mounted Laptop Arm with Foldable Tray](http://www.afcindustries.com/wall-mounted-laptop-arm-with-tray-p952):

[image]

I've seen similar types that were more heavy-duty, for the older heavier CRT monitors, and if you can still find an old one like that it might be extremely cheap now.

Or if you've got a table or desk by the bed, maybe something like this [NB FC35 190cm computer sit-stand work station desk mount laptop table stand monitor bracket shelf with keyboard plate](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/NB-FC35-190cm-computer-sit-stand-work-station-desk-mount-laptop-table-stand-monitor-bracket-shelf/32817804131.html):

[image]

Or maybe just an adjustable bedside table, like this one [Medical Adjustable Overbed Bedside Table with Wheels, Tilt Table for Hospital and Home Use](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DKTRYDB) and put a laptop or keyboard & monitor on top, and move it right out of the way when not needed:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this arrangement would not be suitable for lie down workstation. I'm looking something like this: https://youtu.be/Iwt7qX_7elA

Comment: Your question said you'll be in an adjustable bed reclining, not flat on your back staring straight up with a monitor stuck to the ceiling with magnets! ;-)

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. The bed is parallel to the wall and not perpendicular.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference, attaching one of them to a wall on the right/left side would still let the monitor & keyboard part turn almost any angle, [like in this image](http://www.afcindustries.com/pages/W500H550_5/772424-ergonomic-computer-workstation-arm.jpg)

Comment: Thanks. I am unable to imagine how I can use that to build something like this: https://youtu.be/hGfgFWc1U0I The only difference is I would want the anchoring parts in the side wall.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time to give me the suggestion anyways. Unfortunately I can't upvote your answer due to low reps.

Comment: Everyone can vote, Zid.